# PHP/MYSQL - Only one element from row can be shown, possible issue?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to construct login verifying system in PHP/MySQLi. The `_POST` data is being sent by AJAX request/jQuery, but I have simplified the code as much as possible to allow you to simulate the query even without the unnecessary data. I have also omitted the string verifiers(`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` etc.) for the sake of simplifying

The code (simplified) looks as follows:

```
 $email = "mymail@mail.com";
$haslo = "averyhardpassword12345";

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Email address is not valid.'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($haslo)<3 || strlen($haslo)>20){
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Password must have between 3 and 20 characters.'));
    die($output);
}

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "myDbUsername", "myDbPW", "myDbName");

    $usercheckquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($usercheckquery);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $emailbaza = $row['email'];
    $haslobaza = $row['haslo'];
    echo $haslobaza;
    echo $emailbaza;
    if (password_verify($haslo, $haslobaza) && $email == $emailbaza && !empty($data)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Zalogowano...'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Podany email lub hasło są nieprawidłowe.'));
        die($output);
    }
```

The problem is - i can't manage to find out what's wrong with this code. My final `if` statement never returns true, also I've found out that I can `echo` `$row['email']`, but when i `echo` `$row['haslo']` it returns nothing.

Hope somebody could show me where have I made a mistake.

EDIT:

Oh, and `haslo` is saved in db in `haslo` column and is generated through `password_hash($haslo, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`. `Haslo` column is `varchar(255)`.

Comment: @Scuzzy my god, couldn't believe it was that simple... thanks! :D

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer :)

Comment: It's always good to get a second pair of eyes to see small things like this.

Comment: Question: Would this be safer with a query limit of 1 and no while clause? are you loading a single row or lots of rows? your consumption of the data would overwrite with each loop if there were many rows. every loop pushes the cursor forwards, you may not even need such a loop for just one result.

Comment: it is meant to find a single account connected with given mail, so it should always return just one row. shoud i use `LIMIT 1` within my query? will this force any changes to `while()` loop?

Comment: yes, if you use `LIMIT 1` you can use an `if` statement instead of a while loop, your while will still work, but now you're not expecting many rows, so there's no need for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your while loop need braces to encompass all your usage of `$row`

Otherwise $row will eventually return null and $haslobaza will also be null (*it would be throwing a index error at this point*)

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $emailbaza = $row['email'];
  $haslobaza = $row['haslo'];
}
```

Comment: So let me clarify - unless i brace both variables, it will only set the first one encountered and match with first $row result right?

Comment: Yeah only the first one would get filled out with the result of your last row, and the second one would get hit once the while is exhausted with null, the assignment of $row happens before the while is tested.

Comment: omitting the braces means the while loop only enacts on the next line of code.

Comment: "only enacts on the next line of code". Should be: only the next statement. You can have multiple statements on on a single line ;)

Comment: @PetervanderWal _You are technically correct, the best kind of correct._